# How to ignore Python interactive window for linting in VSCode

Tags: ipython, visual-studio-code, pylance, vscode-python

I would like to disable linting for cells in the interactive window in Visual Studio Code.
I don't see how it is beneficial, since it is not possible to manipulate cells which have already been run (which is different from *.ipynb notebooks). I believe the linting inside the interactive window is a new feature, since it only started a while ago. Currently the only way to remove the linting warnings is removing the cells.

My workflow is usually as follows: I write *.py files and execute them using the "Jupyter: Run Current File in Interactive Window" command, so I can access the variables and experiment.

I already tried adding the following settings to my settings.json file:

```
"python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    "Interactive*",
    "*.interactive"
],
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Example screenshot of linting in interactive window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior was treated as a bug and will be resolved in future releases. See here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8289

Comment: this hasn't been resolved, right? I still have this issue in July 2022, with VS Code 1.69.2

Comment: See the GitHub issue, so far it's only resolved in the insiders version, which is why I personally started using that.

Comment: I still see the issue. Its almost the end of 2023!!